# jQuery .text() returned string isn't behaving like string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am working in a backbone.js in coffeescript and I am trying to select a model out of a collection using the 'where' function. I am passing in a string variable as the second argument and the string is assigned by the return of a jQuery .text() function on a span element.

I do get a string out of the .text() function, but it isn't behaving like a normal string. I can only use a variable as a where() argument if I assign it manually.

**Edit:** I changed $('e.target') to $(e.target), turns out that what I actually have in my gist. I just mis-typed it in summarizing my question. You can see below what return values I am getting on the right.

```
value = $(e.target).text()              # value => 'target text'
value.charAt(0)                           # =>*nothing at all!*  

value = "manually assigned text"          # value => 'manually assigned text'
value.charAt(0)                           # =>* 'm'
```

Here's my snippet for further inspection: https://gist.github.com/4215344

Comment: What if you remove quotes around `'e.target'` ?

Comment: did you try with var value = ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that inspecting value.length was the key. It was something like 36 characters for some reason. I tried in my haml template to call .strip on the variable there, but the extra whitespace wasn't coming from the ruby side.

I just ended up using jQuery's .trim() function.

Here's my new assignment:

```
fontName = $(e.target).text().trim()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
value = $(e.target).text();
```

no quotes around `e.target`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not `.text()`, it's your selector; `'e.target'` is not a valid selector. You probably meant to do:

```
value = $(e.target).text();
```

As is, calling `.text()` on an empty object returns blank.

By removing the quotes, you are actually referencing the `target` property of the event object, which corresponds to an element directly. What you had before was a selector string for `<e>` elements with `class='target'`, which is obviously not what you want.